# How to pass argument to docker command in gitlab-ci with docker executor

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I need to pass the `--network` option to the docker run command in one of my step.
I've tried to configured the gitlab-ci runner with the `network_mode` option, but didn't work

Is there any way to add option to docker command in gitlab-ci ?

Here is my `config.toml` :

```
[[runners]]
  name = "Docker Runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.company.com"
  token = "9621bf2aba8b979b"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    network_mode = "dedicated"
    shm_size = 0
```

**Update**

dedicated is in my network list, try with host, same result

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
0ec4c3c2d4be        bridge              bridge              local
977b613d726e        dedicated           bridge              local
45a0fadc2ce7        host                host                local
9f7251c769ca        none                null                local
```

My IT service in company add a plugin to check argument on container start and i got `AuthZPlugin.AuthZReq: Use of subnet '1.1.1.1/24' is forbidden`

That why i need to explicitly add `--network dedicated`

Answer (score 0):

`network_mode` works for any known networks on thet host, you can [list them](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) with `docker network ls`.

`dedicated` has to be in that list in order for it to work.

I've succesfully done this for the `host` network and can confirm this works.

Comment: Are your runner and docker engine up to date?

Comment: docker engine is in 1.12 & runner is in 10.4

Comment: Is the runner functioning in the default network, so can it perform tasks?

Comment: No as required by the plugin, gitlab-runner is running in dedicated network and it can download image for instance but not start them

Comment: Can't you test without the plugin? To exclude that as a cause for the issue?

Comment: 1/ No I cannot disable it because i'm not admin on daemon

Comment: 2/ Yes I can run container in dedicated network (my gitlab runner is an exemple)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution thanks to [this link](https://medium.com/@tonywooster/docker-in-docker-in-gitlab-runners-220caeb708ca)

I mount a gitlab-dind and use it for my runner by defining env variable `-e DOCKER_HOST=tcp://gitlab-dind:2375` and also use `network_mode = "host"`

My `config.toml` looks like this :

```
[[runners]]
  name = "Runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.company.com"
  token = "ff10e2ae64be1a2f246f5f89e0bc63"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    host = "tcp://gitlab-dind:2375"
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    network_mode = "host"
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```